# How to re-transcode sequence Encore CS4?

Tags: premiere, encore, cs4

A short while ago I made an Encore project from my Premiere CS4 project and spent some time sorting out the menus, credits and timelines, etc. I then told Encore to build the project, which of course caused the rendering of the original Premiere video.

Unfortunately I found some errors in the original project, so went back to Premiere and fixed them. However if I just re-build the video it rebuilds from the original render. I did find the option to set the status of the Premiere Sequence back to Original, but when I build from that, I get a large video full of 'media offline' images... not quite what I meant!

So, how can I build my final video?

In case it matters:

- Original footage: Full HD/50p, destination to "DVD Folder", using the default Encore settings.
- Encore project has a DVD main menu and per-Chapter shortcuts appropriately
  linked up.

I really don't want to have to rebuild the Encore project :(

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your Premiere project is missing assets.  When you embed a Premiere project in to Encore, it will actually run a render in Premiere when you go to encode it in Encore.  If the Premiere project can not find assets that are used in the Sequence that you have embedded, you get a "media offline" image.

I would suggest opening the Premiere project and verifying that it has proper access to all the source files it needs.  I'd also verify that the Premiere project link itself is still intact.